# Page is not showing on ID

Tags: django

In Django when I click on the link which returns an id but the page is not showing in return.

here is url,

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name = 'detail')
```

View.py

```
class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
context_object_name = 'school_detail'
model = models.School
template_name = 'basic_app/school_detail.html'
```

HTML view

```
 {% for school in schools %}
  <h2><li><a href="{{school.id}}">{{school.name}}</a></li></h2>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [{% url %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag to provide the urls in your templates

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' school.id %}">{{school.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `detail` view as below:

```
{% for school in schools %}
    <h2><li><a href="{% url "detail" school.id %}">{{school.name}}</a></li></h2>
{% endfor %}
```